# How to set bindings for Start/StopTrackingTouch for Seekbar using MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I got sort of a typical music player window, music plays and seekbar point is moving while it plays.

I've done it using default `mvvmcross` binding to the property (which is changed through the `EventHandler` binding) like here:

```
 <SeekBar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/playprogress"
      local:MvxBind="Progress ValueOfTimer"
        />
```

So now I want the user to be able to move it forward and back.

I've been trying to bind it like this:

```
 public class PlayWindowView : MvxActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<PlayWindowView, PlayWindowViewModel>();

            SeekBar seek = FindViewById<SeekBar>(Resource.Id.playprogress);

            set.Bind(seek).For("Max").To(viewModel => viewModel.MaxTimerValue);
            set.Bind(seek).For("StopTrackingTouch").To(viewModel => viewModel.PlayProgressChanged);
            set.Apply();
        }

        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.playwindow_view);
        } 
     }
```

Viewmodel part looks like this:

```
public class PlayWindowViewModel : MvxViewModel<ListMenuItemDto>
{

    private long _valueOfTimer;

    public long ValueOfTimer
    {
        get { return _valueOfTimer; }

        set
        {
            _valueOfTimer = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ValueOfTimer);
        }
    }

    //...

    public MvxAsyncCommand<long> PlayProgressChanged
    {
        get { return new MvxAsyncCommand<long>(OnPlayProgressChange);}
    }

    private async Task OnPlayProgressChange(long progr)
    {
        await _playingService.SetTime((int) progr).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

But looks like it's not working. 
I mean, it's not even getting into `OnPlayProgressChange`. But on view is appearing it goes into command `PlayProgressChanged` one time.

How can I bind this event (and such kind of events like `StartTrackingTouch`, `StopTrackingTouch`) to the function correctly?

P.S.
just FYI I using MvvmCross 5

---

**UPD 28.11.2017**

Tried custom binding and even `Progress` binding stoped working now.
So, xaml looks like this now:

```
  <SeekBar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/playprogress"
      local:MvxBind="Progress ValueOfTimer, OnStopTrackingTouch PlayProgressChanged"
        />
```

And binder code is here

```
public class SeekbarStopTrackingTouchEventBinding: MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly SeekBar _seekbar;
    private IMvxAsyncCommand _command;

    public SeekbarStopTrackingTouchEventBinding(SeekBar seekbar) : base(seekbar)
    {
        _seekbar = seekbar;
        _seekbar.StopTrackingTouch += ViewOnStopTrackingTouch;
    }

    private void ViewOnStopTrackingTouch(object sender, SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_command != null)
        {
            _command.Execute(e);
        }
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof (IMvxAsyncCommand); } 
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        _command = (IMvxAsyncCommand)value;
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            _seekbar.StopTrackingTouch -= ViewOnStopTrackingTouch;
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }
}
```

}

In Setup:

```
 protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<SeekBar>("OnStopTrackingTouch", (seekbar) => new SeekbarStopTrackingTouchEventBinding(seekbar)));
    }
```

**UPD2**

Changed binding like this: `local:MvxBind="Progress ValueOfTimer; OnStopTrackingTouch PlayProgressChanged"` (notice `;` here) and event fires now, yes!

But now the thing is - in `binder` `_command` is stays null even after `SetValueImpl` fired and   `_command = (IMvxAsyncCommand)value;` is fine, `value` points to setted ViewModel property.

[image]

How come?

**UPD3**

Found out it can't cast `object` to `IMvxAsyncCommand`.

I fixed that by changing 
 `IMvxAsyncCommand _command` to `IMvxAsyncCommand<SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs> _command`;

Will sum everything up in the answer.

But now I got the question - whats best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know if it's a good way, but for now its working and I'm kinda happy with it.

Hope this would help somebody like me.

***Custom Bindings*** approach is the key here. Really useful stuff is here:

[In MvvmCross how do I do custom bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties)

[MvvmCross Custom Event Binding Event Args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292364/mvvmcross-custom-event-binding-event-args)

[MVVMCross Bindings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495137/mvvmcross-bindings-in-android)

So, in my case, to make app listen to `SeekBar` `OnStopTrackingTouch` event I done this:

Created binding class:

```
public class SeekbarStopTrackingTouchEventBinding: MvxAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        private readonly SeekBar _seekbar;
        private IMvxAsyncCommand<SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs> _command;
        private string  testString;

        public SeekbarStopTrackingTouchEventBinding(SeekBar seekbar) : base(seekbar)
        {
            _seekbar = seekbar;
            _seekbar.StopTrackingTouch += ViewOnStopTrackingTouch;
        }

        private void ViewOnStopTrackingTouch(object sender, SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_command != null)
            {
                _command.Execute(e);
            }
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get { return typeof (IMvxAsyncCommand); } 
        }

        protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
        {
            try
            {
                _command = (IMvxAsyncCommand<SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs>)value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("SOME BINDER FAIL\n\t" + e.Message + "\n", "SOME BINDER FAIL\n\t" + e.Message + "\n");
                throw;
            }
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                _seekbar.StopTrackingTouch -= ViewOnStopTrackingTouch;
            }
            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }

        public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
        {
            get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
        }
    }
```

In `Setup.cs` placed this code:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<SeekBar>("OnStopTrackingTouch", (seekbar) => new SeekbarStopTrackingTouchEventBinding(seekbar)));
}
```

Prepared property in my `ViewModel` and command executing function:

```
    public IMvxAsyncCommand<SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs> PlayProgressChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxAsyncCommand<SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs>(OnPlayProgressChange);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnPlayProgressChange(SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var progr = e.SeekBar.Progress;
        await _playingService.SetTime((int) progr).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

In view layout, inside `local:MvxBind` linked my `ViewModel` command with evend name, provided in `registry.RegisterFactory` in `Setup.cs`

```
  <SeekBar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/playprogress"
      local:MvxBind="Progress ValueOfTimer; OnStopTrackingTouch PlayProgressChanged"
        />
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like here is that your Command wraps a non-portable EventArgs class which is only available on Android. I would probably look into changing this.

Comment: @Cheesebaron well, like, just pass data I need in some simple structure? Or is there other way?